# Ubuntu 18.10 occasional system freeze (maybe graphics related)

Tags: graphics, freeze, system, 18.10, nouveau

Since doing a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.10 on new hardware ([Asus Prime B450-Plus](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-B450-PLUS/), G.Skill Trident 16GB, AMD Rizen 5 1600,  [GTX 750 Ti 2GB](https://www.nvidia.com/gtx-700-graphics-cards/gtx-750ti/)) I’ve had occasional system freezes (locked screen, keyboard and mouse) that require a hard boot (front panel power off/on) to recover. The system freezes seem to occur in graphics-intensive programs like video streaming (Firefox), Darktable photo editing *(very important)*, Google Maps (Firefox), Stellarium but not always. One freeze occurred while editing in the Bluefish html editor and another occurred while the system was idle.
After each freeze event I examined the Logs file after re-booting and found “Important” entries that occurred during the most recent boot:

*9:19:53 AM spice-vdagent: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0

9:19:49 AM gdm3: GLib-GObject: g_object_add_weak_pointer: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

9:19:47 AM kernel: nouveau 0000:06:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 10ac08 [ IBUS ]*

I suspect the fault is occurring in the graphics system because of the reference to [nouveau](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/) but I am strictly a novice at Linux so I’m just guessing at this point. I have not installed the NVIDIA graphics driver.

What's the best course of action to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

First, please reboot into the BIOS/Setup app, following chapter two of your [motherboard manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketAM4/PRIME_B450-PLUS/E14214_PRIME_B450-PLUS_UM_WEB_060418.pdf), and reset to the system defaults. You may have chosen a BIOS/Setup option which drives the hardware faster than it will go.

Secondly, unplug then reseat the memory modules, following instructions on pages 10 and 11 of your [manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketAM4/PRIME_B450-PLUS/E14214_PRIME_B450-PLUS_UM_WEB_060418.pdf). While you're doing that, compare the memory module part number to the part numbers on the Asus Prime B450-Plus [Qualified Vendor List](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketAM4/TUF_B450M-PLUS_GAMING/Memory_QVL_For_AMD_Ryzen_2000_Series_Processors.pdf?_ga=2.198865391.153547891.1544207219-2107724240.1541781616) and confirm it is listed there.

If the issue persists, I certainly would consider installing the [manufacturer's driver](https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/140135) for your [GTX 750 Ti 2GB](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-750-ti), for [nouveau freezes are not unheard of](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2376704).

And, last but not least, the we-only-support-this-for-nine-months [interim releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) of Ubuntu like 18.10 are not what I'd use for new hardware. Stick with [18.04 LTS](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.1/ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso), or better yet, [16.04 LTS](http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso) until you know the system is stable, then you can go to the bleeding edge.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try all these suggestions. I didn't change much in the bios from defaults but I'll reset them them anyway.